# Populate column from table X with value from table Y

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-update

A fellow developer changed all the values in the `userid` column of table `map`.  I need them changed back, because `userid` is also a key in the `profiles` table.  Thankfully, for reasons that aren't worth going into, `map` and `profiles` share another column in common, `employeeId`.

So I'd like to take all the values for `userid` as found in `profiles` and overwrite the values found in `userid` the matching row of `map`.

My instinct is to do something like this:

```
UPDATE map,profiles
SET map.userid = profiles.userid
WHERE map.employeeId = profiles.employeeId
```

But SQLServer 2005 doesn't care to have two tables in the UPDATE clause.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can have FROM clause in the update:

```
UPDATE m 
SET m.userid = profiles.userid
from map m
inner join profiles on m.employeeId = profiles.employeeId
```

Comment: This aliased form is clearer, IMHO. It links the UPDATE with the FROM more explicitly.

Answer (score 3):

In T-SQL syntax, the Update portion contains what you want to update, and the FROM *may* contain additional source(s) of data.

Try the following

```
UPDATE map
SET map.userid = profiles.userid
FROM profiles
WHERE map.employeeId = profiles.employeeId
```

Update Syntax: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177523.aspx